# In R, how do I get an if statement to recognize if input in double curly brackets is a certain value?

Tags: r, rlang, curly-braces

I'm building a function where users can select a column from a list of options, and within the function, I want to do an if statement where, if the x variable is one of the options that the function is designed to work with, it will generate the plot. Otherwise, it will print an error message.

However, when I try to do `if({{x_variable}} == ses)`--the correct variable in this example--I keep getting

```
Error in make_plot(test_data, x_variable = ses) : object 'ses' not found
```

That's the same error I get for `if(enquo(x_variable) == ses)` and `if(!!x_variable == ses)`

The correct answer will produce the plot when x_variable is ses and will print the error when x_variable is anything else.

Here's a sample dataset and my function (that does not work collectively, but each individual part does):

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang) #if enquo() is needed

test_data <- tibble(ses = c(rep(c("High", "Mid", "Mid Low", "Low"), 2)),
                    total = c(10, 20, 20, 30, 9, 11, 40, 60))

make_plot <- function(data, x_variable) {

  if({{x_variable}} == "ses") {
ggplot(data = test_data, aes(x = {{x_variable}}, y = total)) +
  geom_col()
  } else {
    print("This function isn't designed for this variable, sorry!")
  }
}

make_plot(test_data, x_variable = ses)
make_plot(test_data, x_variable = anything_else)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
make_plot(test_data, x_variable = "ses")
```

or alternatively:

```
ses <- "ses"
make_plot(test_data, x_variable = ses)
```

This error means that the object `ses` is not declared.

---

If you want to be able to pass **undeclared** objects such as `ses` as an input, you could use `substitute(x_variable)` or `deparse(substitute(x_variable))`

```
make_plot <- function(data, x_variable) {
  #print(deparse(substitute(x_variable)))
  if(deparse(substitute(x_variable)) == "ses") {
    ggplot(data = test_data, aes(x = ses, y = total)) +
      geom_col()
  } else {
    print("This function isn't designed for this variable, sorry!")
  }
}
```

[image]

This is non-standard evaluation however, so make sure this is indeed what you're after as it can lead to surprising behaviours.

This explains the difference between both options, from [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @gaut's elaborate answer, or if it's easier for you to remember (or understand how `{{` work), you would need the following to use the curly brackets.

`names(select(data, {{x_variable}})) == "ses"`